# How to recover from "Unavailable credentials failed to obtain metadata" after revoking permissions at myaccount.google.com/permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-photos-api

I wanted to use the Google Photos Java API: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started-java

so I followed all the steps on the link above and I was able to run the demos fine.  However, I then went to revoke the test app's permissions on my google account by going to:
https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

and that's when the problem started.  All subsequent attempts to run the demo app are now unsuccessful.  They all return:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata
```

Despite clearing cookies, signing in and out of my Google account, recreating the OAuth Client ID, nothing seems to make it work again.  It doesn't seem I can explicitly re-enable my test app from https://myaccount.google.com/permissions. Any help or tips are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could figure out how to solve this problem was to create a new Google Cloud project.  Then I followed the tutorial again and authorized my Google account to allow the new Google Cloud project access.